# Android LocationProvider will not update

Tags: java, android, location-provider

I've set the setInterval to 10 seconds, and the setFastestInterval to 1 second, but the app doesn't update the address location. It's only loaded once.

I want it to be loaded more than once. Should I put the mLocationProvider in a loop?

Thanks for any help.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationProvider.LocationCallback {
    private LocationProvider mLocationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find my location
        mLocationProvider = new LocationProvider(this, this);
    }


    public void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        float currentAccuracy = location.getAccuracy();
    }
}
```

LocationProvider:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class LocationProvider implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    public abstract interface LocationCallback {
        public void handleNewLocation(Location location);
    }

    public static final String TAG = LocationProvider.class.getSimpleName();

    /*
    * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
    * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
    */
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
    private Context mContext;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    public LocationProvider(Context context, LocationCallback callback) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mLocationCallback = callback;

        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

        mContext = context;
    }

    public void connect() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connected.");

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            // public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                        int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Permission missing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
        else {
            mLocationCallback.handleNewLocation(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
        * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
        * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
        * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
        * error.
        */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution() && mContext instanceof Activity) {
            try {
                Activity activity = (Activity)mContext;
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(activity, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                * PendingIntent
                */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
            * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
            * user with the error.
            */
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLocationCallback.handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}
```

Ive read https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates but it didn't help me much.

Comment: Are you getting a location or null from the getLastLocation call?  If not null, you won't ever request the ongoing updates from requestLocationUpdates.

Comment: you have not done pretty much anything in your 'handleNewLocation' method. Are you saying the lat/lon you are never getting this method invoked ? or the values in this method  are never udated?

Comment: I get data in handleNewLocation method one time. Real data. But it doesnt update. I was thinking it should update every 10 seconds.